# StatefulJ create timeout event

Tags: java, fsm

Has some of You used statefulJ(http://www.statefulj.org/) framework and know how to implement event that will occour after certain time? I mean something like "Timer event" in Activiti
(http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#timerEventDefinitions)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there a standard "StatefulJ" way, but you could always create a timer and in the action send your own event to the FSM.